# how to transform a draggable image into a div when dropped

Tags: jquery, image, html

My name's Adam and I'm a junior programmer. I'm starting to understand how Jquery UI works, but I need some help. I want to drag a small "image" onto a blank canvas(a blank "div"), and when I drop it I want the "image" to turn into a "div" with specific elements inside.

It's basically a drag and drop that transforms the dropped "image" into a "div".

I'm open to any suggestions on how to accomplish this. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5qyf6/5/

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

```
var replaceImgWithContent = function ($el) {
    $el.wrap($('<div></div>', {
        'html': '<b>New content</b>',
        'css': {
            'width': $el.outerWidth() + 'px',
            'height': $el.outerHeight() + 'px',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'left': $el.offset().left + 'px',
            'top': $el.offset().top + 'px'
        }
    }));
    $el.remove();
}
$('img').draggable({
    create: function () {
        $('img').on('dragstop', function (e, ui) {
            div_offset = $('div').offset();
            img_offset = $('img').offset();
            alert('stopped');
            if (img_offset.top > div_offset.top && img_offset.top < div_offset.top + $('div').outerHeight() && img_offset.left > div_offset.left && img_offset.left < div_offset.left + $('div').outerWidth()) {
                replaceImgWithContent($('img'));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Another solution of course would be to start with a div-wrapped image right away. So you could apply draggable() to that wrapper div and you would not need to "restart" it for every image instance you use.

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time to show me that. Much appreciated. I'm going to play around with the code and try to familiarize myself with it as much as I can.